# Find integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ with $55a + 65b + 143c= 1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm not sure if this is a diophantine equation with three variables or not, but I can't find any resources for it. I am thinking there must be some sort of solving for two and then substituting the answer into another two variables. Unfortunately my notes are not sufficient.

How would I go about solving? Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use standard two-variable theory to solve $55s+65t=5$. (Find $x$ and $y$ such that $11x+13y=1$.)

Then use standard theory to solve $5u+143v=1$. Then put things together.

Comment: Yes I tried something like this. I will try again. So you're letting u=55a + 65b

Comment: You can do it more informally by letting $c=2$. Then $1-2(143)$ is divisible by $5$, so $55x+65y=1-2(143)$ has a solution. Just solve $11p+13q=1$ and multiply by $-57$. I was sketching a more general approach.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your answer should be $(x,y,z) = (-342,285,2)$. Check the math by working out on your own though.

Comment: There is a "double infinity" (two free parameters) of solutions.

Comment: Yes! I got the same solution too. So that is just a particular solution is it and you could set c to say k(2) so you could solve the remaining equation in the same way with different solutions for a and b

Comment: You could find the *general* solutions of the equations in two variables. The basic idea is that if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, and $x_0a+y_0b=1$, the general solution of $xa+yb=1$ is $x=x_0-kb$, $y=y_0+ka$. But it looks as if they are not asking for general solution. Full details are somewhat messy.